# How to Unit Test Component After fromEvent FileReader.loadended

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, angular-forms

I am trying to write a unit test to assert that a variable in a component has changed after form submission in a multi-step form scenario. The multi-step form is functional, but not unit testable. I am also not sure how to debug this to determine the root cause of the test failure.

Given the following functional component method:

```
  submitFileForm(form: NgForm): void {
    if (this.uploadFile) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      fromEvent(reader, 'error')
        .subscribe((e: ProgressEvent) => {
          console.error(e);
          reader.abort();
        });
      fromEvent(reader, 'loadend')
        .pipe(map(() => btoa(reader.result as string)))
        .subscribe(() => {
          // This works, but not in the test.
          component.step = 1;
        }, (err) => {
          console.error(err);
          this.step = -1;
        });

      reader.readAsText(this.uploadFile, 'UTF-8');
    }
 }
```

And the following test:

```
  it('should go from step 0 to step 1', () => {
    const mockBlob: any = new Blob([
      `A,B,C\naaaa,bbb,ccc`,
    ], { type: 'text/csv' });
    mockBlob.name = 'my.csv';
    const mockFile = mockBlob as File;
    component.uploadFile = mockFile;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.submitFileForm(component.fileForm);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // This fails. component.step is 0. After the test is finished step is 1.
    expect(component.step).toEqual(1);
  }
```

A full example is at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zr3nej and https://angular-zr3nej.stackblitz.io/ that shows additional details. These are in Angular 8.

I've tried

- Abstracting the reader into its own service.
- Wrapping the fromEvent using `NgZone.run` and `NgZone.runOutsideAngular`.
- Wrapping the `NgZone.run(() => { component.step = 1; });`
- Using a BehaviorSubject for the form step.
- Ticking ApplicationRef.
- Using `fixture.whenStable()` in the test.

But I think that this is probably due to a fundamental misunderstanding of Angular or Zone, and a how to correctly register a pending task for the Angular component. There could also be a better way to structure the code so that it is unit testable in a different way. Maybe instead of waiting for form submit the reader could always be reading? Or maybe async/await, but I am not as familiar with those patterns when combined with RxJS and Angular.

I haven't tried injecting `ChangeDetectionRef` because I've run into trouble in the past with making *that* testable.

The ngSwitch pattern here is probably not the cleanest, but it should still be possible in my opinion. Personally I would probably break it into individual components, but sometimes we need to adhere to common code styles.

- [Observable fromEvent do not activate detectionchange on angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212459/observable-fromevent-do-not-activate-detectionchange-on-angular) seems to be similar, but in that case the actual functional aspect doesn't work, not the test.
- [Unit testing fromEvent observable withLatestFrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52623803/unit-testing-fromevent-observable-with-withlatestfrom) doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: I think that abstracting out FileReader to a service, and then mocking the return observable will work. I'm not sure why in my actual application that wasn't working the other day, but there may have been side effects based on the complexity of the form.

Answer (score 2):

Abstracting out to a service seems to work today. I may have had some other side effects, but I do like this pattern a lot more and it looks cleaner in the component. I'm sorry if I wasted any one's time. I won't accept this answer because there's probably a better answer that explains what I was running into.

```
  export class FileReaderService {
      read(file: File): Observable<string> {
        return Observable.create((observer: Observer<string>) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onerror = () => {
            reader.abort();
            observer.error('An error occurred reading the file.');
          };

          reader.onloadend = () => {
            observer.next(reader.result as string);
            observer.complete();
          };

          reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
        });
      }
    }
```

component change:

```
  submitFileForm(form: NgForm): void {
    if (this.uploadFile) {
      this.fileReaderService.read(this.uploadFile)
        .subscribe(() => {
          component.step = 1;
        }, (err) => {
          console.error(err);
          this.step = -1;
        });
     }
   }
```

test change:

```
  it('should go from step 0 to step 1', () => {
    const contents = `A,B,C\naaaa,bbb,ccc`;
    const reader = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FileReaderService);
    spyOn(reader, 'read').and.returnValue(of(contents));

    const mockBlob: any = new Blob([contents]), { type: 'text/csv' });
    mockBlob.name = 'my.csv';
    const mockFile = mockBlob as File;
    component.uploadFile = mockFile;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.submitFileForm(component.fileForm);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.step).toEqual(1);
  }
```

Comment: Well done, you wrote the script, starred in the film and watched it at the cinema :-) I also like the style of the solution and may give it a go this afternoon.